# maintaining TreeSet sort as object changes value

Tags: java, collections, refresh, treeset, sortedset

I've got a object that defines a 'natural sort order' using Comparable<>.
These are being stored in TreeSets.

Other than removing and re-adding the object, is there another way to update the sort when the members that are used to define the sort order are updated?

Comment: Is this just morbid curiosity, or are you looking for a specific benefit, say in performance or code simplicity?

Comment: I was looking for a simple noninvasive way to maintain the sort order of a collection as events update the objects within it. 
Altering the membership has side effects on other consumers of the collection. 
IMO, triggering a resort of an element seems like basic functionality for a sorted collection.

Comment: GUIs have the same problem, and MVC is the solution. The GUI which corresponds to your `TreeSet` calls `update` in periodic intervals, or the controller (observer pattern) gets triggered by the model if a value changes

Comment: The fingered by architecture pretty accurately. The TreeSet is my model of DOTs listening to a websocket jms events which then relay the Model updates thru the presenter/controller layer to view widgets.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As others have noted, there is no in-built way. But you can always subclass that TreeSet, with your constructor(s) of choice, and add in the required functionality:

```
public class UpdateableTreeSet<T extends Updateable> extends TreeSet<T> {

    // definition of updateable
    interface Updateable{ void update(Object value); }

    // constructors here
    ...

    // 'update' method; returns false if removal fails or duplicate after update
    public boolean update(T e, Object value) {
       if (remove(e)) {
           e.update(value);
           return add(e);
       } else { 
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

From then on, you will have to call `((UpdateableTreeSet)mySet).update(anElement, aValue)` to update the sorting value and the sorting itself. This does require you to implement an additional `update()` method in your data object.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, found this thread and tucuxi's answer (thanks!) based on which I implemented my own `UpdateableTreeSet`. My version provides means to

- iterate over such a set,
- schedule (deferred) element updates/removals from within the loop
- without having to create a temporary copy of the set and finally
- do all the updates/removals as a bulk operation after the loop has ended.

`UpdateableTreeSet` hides a lot of the complexity from the user. In addition to deferred bulk updates/removals, single-element update/removal as shown by tucuxi still remains available in the class.

Update 2012-08-07: The class is available in a little [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/UpdateableTreeSet) including an introductory README with schematic sample code as well as unit tests showing how (not) to use it in more detail.

Comment: I like the idea - it would just imply placing the "deferred-update" array inside the UpdateableTreeSet, and then calling "do-deferred-updates" to first remove all of the updates, and then re-insert them.

Comment: As my code example implies, this is what I have done. It is not just an idea, it is a real implementation. Have you followed the link to the source code and also checked out other files in the project to see how the class is used in more complicated cases?

Comment: No need - the idea is clear enough, and although your explanation is somewhat over-lengthy, I up-voted it as useful.

Comment: I have reacted on your comment that the posting was over-lengthy and shortened it dramatically. I also removed the sample code snippet. Instead there is a pointer to a dedicated Git repository with the full code now for further reference. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need to use a `Set`, then you're out of luck, I think.

I'm going to throw in a wildcard, though - if your situation is flexible enough to work with a `List` instead of a `Set`, then you can use `Collections.sort()` to re-sort the `List` on demand. This should be performant, if the `List` order doesn't have to be changed much.

Comment: Not much of an advantage to doing that - Set guarantees fast lookup, insertion and removal, while a List would require using Collections.binarySearch first to locate the element. It is better to stick to removal and re-insertion.

Comment: I realise that, which is why I said "if your situation is flexible enough". The performance requirements *may* be loose enough to permit a `List` to be practical.

Comment: @tucuxi binary search in a List is O(log n).  Lookup in a TreeSet?  Also O(log n).

Comment: @Kevin but you have to go through the motions of implementing versions of add(), remove() and contains() that do binary searches internally. In essence, you are reimplementing TreeSet with a sorted list inside. That is why I wrote that removal&reinsertion seemed easier. Not because of performance, but because of coding time.

Comment: I liked this idea if the collection could be sorted in place rather than create a new instance.

Comment: I think if you will often be modifying the objects, but there aren't very many and their order doesn't change very much, it's easier to implement a wrapper that performs a lot of Collections.sort. At least for my use case this seems a lot easier than (somehow) remembering to remove the object from the TreeSet, then modify it, then readd it every time.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion, also, insertion is still O(n) in a list, unless you use a linked list, but then lookup is no longer O(log n).

Answer (score 1):

Only built in way is to remove and re-add.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to know whether your objects will be changing by small increments or large.  If each change is very small, you would do very well to put your data in a List that you keep sorted.  To do this, you have to

1. binarySearch to find the index of the element
2. modify the element
3. while the element is greater than its righthand neighbor, swap it with its righthand neighbor
4. or if that didn't happen: while the element is less than its lefthand neighbor, swap it with its lefthand neighbor.

But you have to make sure no one can change the element without going through "you" to do it.

**EDIT:** Also! Glazed Lists has some support for just this:

http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.5.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/ObservableElementList.html

Answer (score 1):

I looked up this problem when I was trying to implement a kinetic scroll pane similar to the apple iPhone wheel scrolls. The items in the `TreeSet` are this class:

```
/**
 * Data object that contains a {@code DoubleExpression} bound to an item's
 * relative distance away from the current {@link ScrollPane#vvalueProperty()} or
 * {@link ScrollPane#hvalueProperty()}. Also contains the item index of the
 * scrollable content.
 */
private static final class ItemOffset implements Comparable<ItemOffset> {

    /**
     * Used for floor or ceiling searches into a navigable set. Used to find the
     * nearest {@code ItemOffset} to the current vValue or hValue of the scroll
     * pane using {@link NavigableSet#ceiling(Object)} or
     * {@link NavigableSet#floor(Object)}.
     */
    private static final ItemOffset ZERO = new ItemOffset(new SimpleDoubleProperty(0), -1);

    /**
     * The current offset of this item from the scroll vValue or hValue. This
     * offset is transformed into a real pixel length of the item distance from
     * the current scroll position.
     */
    private final DoubleExpression scrollOffset;

    /** The item index in the list of scrollable content. */
    private final int index;

    ItemOffset(DoubleExpression offset, int index) {
        this.scrollOffset = offset;
        this.index = index;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ItemOffset other) {
        double d1 = scrollOffset.get();
        double d2 = other.scrollOffset.get();

        if (d1 < d2) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (d1 > d2) {
            return 1;
        }

        // Double expression has yet to be bound
        // If we don't compare by index we will
        // have a lot of values ejected from the
        // navigable set since they will be equal.
        return Integer.compare(index, other.index);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return index + "=" + String.format("%#.4f", scrollOffset.get());
    }
}
```

The `DoubleExpression` may take a moment to be bound in a runLater task of the JavaFX platform, this is why the index is included in this wrapper class.

Since the `scrollOffset` is always changing based on the user scroll position on the scroll wheel, we need a way to update. Usually the order is always the same, since the offset is relative to the item index position. The index never changes, but the offset could be negative or positive depending on the items relative distance from the current vValue or hValue property of the `ScrollPane`.

To update **on demand only when needed**, simply follow the guidance of the above answer by Tucuxi.

```
ItemOffset first = verticalOffsets.first();
verticalOffsets.remove(first);
verticalOffsets.add(first);
```

where *verticalOffsets* is a `TreeSet<ItemOffset>`. If you do a print out of the
set each time this update snippet is called, you will see that it is updated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a out-of-the-box way to do it.

You could use an **observer pattern** that notifies the treeset whenever you change a value inside an element, then it removes and re-inserts it.

In this way you can implicitly keep the list sorted without caring of doing it by hand.. of course this approach will need to extend `TreeSet` by modifying the behaviour of insertion (setting the observed/notify mechanics on the just added item)

Comment: I don't think that will work. If the element's value changes in a way that affects the sort order, it's quite likely that you will be *unable to find it in the tree* or remove it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt there is no reason it will not work, this is the exact same solution of the best answer BUT with an additionnal observer pattern. by the way this is also implemented like that in many  library in different languages, for exemple QT c++ lib use a sorted list that observes a model

Comment: @DamienMIRAS: No, this is not the same solution, and as stated it most definitely will not work. The accepted answer first removes the element, then changes its value, then reinserts it. That works. An Observer will not work because if you notify it after changing the value, you have already corrupted the internal state of the TreeSet, and if you notify it before changing the value, it can't do anything yet. It only works if the Observer ends up actually changing the value like in the accepted answer, but then it's not really an Observer (and won't work with multiple ones).

Comment: Damn yes you are true ! I missed that "little detail" ^^ thanks. It could work by encapsulating the internal value  : onChange the observable notify the Set, then the instance  is removed from the set, then the field of the instance is update and finaly added back to the set. But I find this is an overkill, it could be fun to have a try on a github.