# benefit of having a treeset over a manually sorted set

Tags: java, set, treeset

In collection we could sort the set or map as per to our requirement. Treeset or TreeMap also provides the sorted collection. Is there any benefit of using treeset when we require sorted collection

Comment: One reason could be that you wouldn't have to worry about forgetting (may be by mistake) to sort where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Can you define "manually sorted set"? Does it make sense to re-invent wheel when something available?

Comment: do you mean manually sorted means by explicitly calling `collections.sort()`?

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The posters before me have not mentioned an important criterion: If the elements in your collection change their state often *after* insertion, i.e. you need to re-sort the same collection several times, maybe a `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` are not ideal because elements are only sorted during insertion, never afterwards. I.e. if you change the sorting key of an element in a `TreeSet`/`TreeMap`, it will not be re-sorted automatically. You need to remove the element from the collection before updating it and re-add it after updating it, so as to make sure it will be inserted at the right spot. You could use my [UpdateableTreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169301/1082681) to help you keep a `TreeSet` sorted.

Having said the above, you can conclude that in this case maybe an unsorted collection plus using `Collections.sort()` on demand might be the easier way to go. Which way is faster overall depends on your situation. I guess that `UpdateableTreeSet` should pretty much help you keep sorting of an existing collection limited to the places where you really change sorting keys.

Answer (score 2):

**TreeSet**

It is always beneficial to have sorted set when ever it is require.

- log(n) time cost for the basic operations (add, remove and contains)
- TreeSet have few handy methods to deal with the ordered set like first(), last(), headSet(), and tailSet() etc
- The items inside TreeSet are automatically sorted according to their natural ordering if you are not giving your own comparator.

Also please go through the TreeSet documentation. [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said, TreeSet has some pretty cool capabilities, like the ability to quickly obtain a sub-set.

Outside of that, it's a question of how often you need things sorted.  If you are going to create 100 sets, and only need 1 or 2 of them sorted, then the overhead of sorting during insertion is probably not worth it.  But if you are going to sort the set even a single time, tree set will be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is

**`TreeSet` keeps the data sorted all the time and a set which you maintain by manually sorted may not be sorted at all times.**

So `TreeSet` is recommended if you don't want to keep sorting the set all the time.