# Is there a way to get the index of an object in a list without using a loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, equals

The trick is that this object `MediaContainerModel` inherits `equals(Object)` directly from `Object` and I can't and don't want to override `equals` in its class definition. This is what I have at the moment:

```
private void addMediaContainer(MediaContainerModel newMediaContainer, ProductModel product) {
    List<MediaContainerModel> galleryImages = new ArrayList<>(product.getGalleryImages());
    MediaContainerModel inserted = null;

    // if a MediaContainer with same qualifier as newMediaContainer already exists, replace it 
    // with the new one to prevent duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < galleryImages.size(); i++) {
        if (galleryImages.get(i).getQualifier().equals(newMediaContainer.getQualifier())) {
            inserted = galleryImages.set(i, newMediaContainer);
        }
    }
    // if not, add it
    if (inserted == null) {
        galleryImages.add(newMediaContainer);
        galleryImages.sort((image1, image2) -> image2.getQualifier().compareTo(image1.getQualifier()));
    }
    product.setGalleryImages(galleryImages);
}
```

I want to do the same thing without the ugly for-loop by overriding `MediaContainerModel.equals(Object)` for this method only so I can use `List.indexOf(Object)` or something with lambdas. Is this possible in Java? If so how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without using a loop

I bet you are looking for the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) way:

```
List<MediaContainerModel> galleryImages = new ArrayList<>(product.getGalleryImages());

galleryImages.stream()
    .filter(image -> newMediaContainer.getQualifier()                 // filter the equal ones
                                      .equals(image.getQualifier()))
    .findAny()                                                        // find any existing
    .ifPresent(image -> {                                             // add if present
        galleryImages.add(newMediaContainer);
        galleryImages.sort(Comparator.comparing(MediaContainerModel::getQualifier));
    });

product.setGalleryImages(galleryImages);
```

Few notes:

- The filtering uses exhaustive iteration as well as `for-loop` which means that all elements are iterated and multiple equal `MediaContainerModel` objects with same qualifiers. That's fine as long as you want to find if there is any qualified (`findAny`). Otherwise, to find the last one, you have to replace the line with:

  ```
  .reduce((first, second) -> second)
  ```
- The result using Java Stream API is a bit clumsy. I see you insert a new element and sort the list which means your intention is to keep the list always sorted. If there are no duplicate values allowed, I recommend using rather [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which keeps the elements sorted upon addition or deletion. The whole solution would be the way easier:

  ```
  Set<MediaContainerModel> galleryImages = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MediaContainerModel::getQualifier));
  galleryImages.addAll(product.getGalleryImages());
  galleryImages.add(newMediaContainer);                      // won't be added if is already present
  product.setGalleryImages(new ArrayList<>(galleryImages));
  ```

  ... if the `ProductModel` uses `Collection` or `Set` over `List`, then the last line is more straightforward:

  ```
  product.setGalleryImages(galleryImages);
  ```

Comment: If I use a `TreeSet`, I would want to update it if it contains a `MediaContainerModel` with the same `qualifier` as `newMediaContainerModel`. Would that be ```galleryImages.remove(newMediaContainer); galleryImages.add(newMediaContainer);``` ? I check for duplicates by comparing `qualifier` but other fields might be different.

Comment: Yes, correct - you need to remove and add the item since `TreeSet::add` doesn't replace the value if present. Check this relevant question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579679/maintaining-treeset-sort-as-object-changes-value